# jasig fail to redirect using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cas

I try to add CAS(jasig) into my website. The website is using spring boot. 
There are two filters added like this:

```
  /***
   * Set sso security filter.
   * @return FilterRegistrationBean
   */
  @Bean(name="FilterRegistrationBean2")
  public FilterRegistrationBean configValidationFilter() {


      final FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter());
      bean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

      final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("casServerUrlPrefix", "https://mycas");
      params.put("serverName", "http://localhost:8080");
      params.put("redirectAfterValidation", "true");

      bean.setInitParameters(params);
      bean.setOrder(2);
      bean.setEnabled(true);
      return bean;
  }

    /***
     * Set sso security filter.
     * @return FilterRegistrationBean
     */
  @Bean(name="FilterRegistrationBean1")
    public FilterRegistrationBean configAuthenticationFilter() {

        final FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter());
        bean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("casServerLoginUrl", "https://mycas/login");
        params.put("serverName", "http://localhost:8080");
        params.put("redirectAfterValidation", "true");

        bean.setInitParameters(params);
        bean.setOrder(1);
        bean.setEnabled(true);
        return bean;
    }
```

I could see the login page. But after confirm username&pwd, I received 200 instead of 302. There are not errors in the frontend & backend. But I cannot redirect my login page.

Another spring project using web.xml works.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found any solution?